# Linking directories inside directories in Bash

Tags: regex, bash, symlink

My script processes files.lst and it has a loop that looks like this

```
while read src_column dest_column; do
    if [[ -d $src ]]; then
        src="../../default/$src_column/*"
    else
        src="../../default/$src_column"
    fi
    pushd $dest
    ln -s $src .
    popd
done < files.lst
```

files.lst

```
#~source~          ~destination~
data                dir1
default/def1.txt    new1.txt
data                dir2/dir22/dir222
default/def1.txt    dir2/dir22/dir222/new1.txt
default             dir2/dir22
default/def2.txt    dir2/dir22/ne2.txt
```

The cases should be like this:

if destinations are `dir2/dir22/dir222` or `dir2/dir22/dir222/new1.txt`
the starting prefix of `$src` should be `../../../../default`

if destinations are `dir2/dir22` or `dir2/dir22/new2.txt`
the starting prefix of `$src` should be `../../../default`

if destinations are `dir2` or `dir2/new2.txt`
the starting prefix of `$src` should be `../../default`

The problem is I don't know how I will count the directories how deep they are. What approach should I do? I am thinking of regex but I got no idea how I'll use it.

Comment: How do you differentiate that `dir2/dir22/dir222` is a directory & `dir2/dir22/new2.txt` is a file? You could change `dir2/dir22/dir222` to `dir2/dir22/dir222/`, to make things easier.

Comment: I see! that's a good idea. How can i convert dir2/dir22/dir222/ to ../../../?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed` to calculate the paths...:

```
while read src_column dest_column; do
    if [[ -d $src ]]; then
        dest_column="$dest_column/"
    fi
    src_prefix="$(sed -r 's|/[^/]*$|/|; s|//*|/|g; s|[^/]+|..|g' <<< "./$dest_column")default"

# sed command details:
# First expression: strip out any file.txt from $dest_column
# 2nd expression: Change duplicate / to single / (e.g. a/b//c// to a/b/c
# Last expression: Change any path to `..`

#Finally append the missing ../default.

    if [[ -d $src ]]; then
        src="$src_prefix/$src_column/*"
    else
        src="$src_prefix/$src_column"
    fi
    pushd $dest
    ln -s $src .
    popd
done < files.lst
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your sed expression and everything works fine but I have a problem. If `$dest_column` is `new.txt` the output is `....` instead of `../..`

Comment: did you add something?